# String is null or empty datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I want my first column of my datagrid not to be empty. So i created this check if string is null or empty.

```
private void provjeri_unose()
    {
        string šifra = "šifra";
        for (int t = 0; t < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; t++)
        {
            šifra = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[t].Cells[0].Value);
        }
        Proizvod.Šifra = šifra;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Proizvod.Šifra))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Šifra mora biti unesena");
        }
    }
```

I do enter value inside datagrid in first column, but it still shows messagebox, which should only be shown if no data is entered inside first column.
My question is, where did i make mistake.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting, I think you have an empty last row and since you are iterating all the rows it is showing the last row's cell value.

Comment: + do you want to make sure there is no empty cell in the first column of your grid or do you want to make sure the cell in the first row of your first column is not empty?

Comment: I think you gave me idea, changed code a little bit and added -1 to counter. Now works!

Comment: I want it to check each cell in first column if not empty. Now it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
 private void provjeri_unose()
    {
        string šifra = "šifra";
        for (int t = 0; t < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; t++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[t];
            if (row.IsNewRow) break;
            šifra = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[t].Cells[0].Value);
            Proizvod.Šifra = šifra;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Proizvod.Šifra))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Šifra mora biti unesena");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This will not check the cell in the last row. Change `for (int t = 0; t < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; t++)` into `for (int t = 0; t < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; t++)` to make it work

Answer (score -1):

```
            gridgetrequest.DataSource = dt;
            gridgetrequest.DataBind();

            string emptydata = dt.Rows[0]["processdate"].ToString();

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                if (emptydata == "")
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridgetrequest.Rows)
                    {
                        Label checkPRNNo = (Label)row.FindControl("lblprocessdate");

                        checkPRNNo.Text = "anand";
                    }



                }
            }
```